# Ошибка The property is not a navigation property of entity type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Пытаюсь установить связь, с таблицей другой в asp net core, у меня выдает ошибку:

> The property 'Name' is not a navigation property of entity type
>   'Product'. The 'Include(string)' method can only be used with a '.'
>   separated list of navigation property names.

Мой код:

Модель ProductDetail

```
[ForeignKey("Product")]
public int? ProductId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("ProductId")]
public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

public int? CategoryId { get; set; }

public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

public int Count { get; set; }
```

Модель Product

```
public class Product
{
    [Required] public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<ProductDetail> ProductDetail { get; set; }

}
```

Контроллер:

```
var blog2 = _context.ProductDetails
                    .Include(b => b.Product)
                    .ThenInclude(b => b.Name)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Всякими способами пробывал установить связь - не работает.
Гугл перерыл - не работают там решение.
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы делаете Include - то указываете навигационные свойства. В данном примере вы делаете выборку из таблицы ProductDetails и .Product — это навигационное свойство (оно указывает на другую таблицу).

После того, как вы подключили таблицу продуктов вы можете через .ThenInclude указывать навигационные свойства из таблицы продуктов. Допустим, в сущности продукт указано навигационное свойство "бренд продукта":

Model Product

```
[ForeignKey("Brand")]
public int BrandId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("BrandId")]
public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
```

В таком случае вы могли бы в своём запросе указать это навигационное свойство бренд:

```
var blog2 = _context.ProductDetails
                    .Include(pd => pd.Product)
                    .ThenInclude(p => p.Brand)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Однако Name - это не навигационное свойство продукта, это вероятнее всего просто строка:

Model Product

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

И нужно понимать, что когда вы указываете в `.Include` или `.ThenInclude` навигационные свойства — вы подключаете сразу всю таблицу базы (сущность в терминах EF) целиком. Поэтому вам нет необходимости указывать поле Name - у вас и Name и все остальные поля таблицы продуктов подключились. (А в моём примере — вам доступны все поля таблиц ProductDetails, Products и Brands)

Поэтому эту строчку вам нужно просто исключить, она не нужна. Через Include подключаются только модели и при подключении модели сразу все её поля доступны в запросе.

После того, как вы передадите в представление вашу модель:

var model = _context.ProductDetails
                    .Include(b => b.Product)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

Вы сможете использовать не только поля ProductDetail, но и Product:

```
<table>
    @foreach(var pd in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@pd.Id</td>
            <td>@pd.Title</td>
            <td>@pd.Count</td>
            <td>@pd.Product.Name</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

PS Для получения продукта можно идти напрямую и не подключать никакие дополнительные таблицы:

```
var product = _context.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 12345);
if(product == null)
    throw new Exception();

var productName = product.Name;
```

Comment: Все равно не получается что-то. Будьте добры, посмотрите, может что-то не так сделал. (Атрибуты ставил также)
https://pastebin.com/b8zJiLuk

Comment: @Andrey А что хотите вывести-то в итоге?

Comment: Я хочу с таблицы ProductDetails - получить данные таблицы product.
P.S если надо (малоли) - вот связи.  Товар(Product), Категории(Category), ТоварКатегории(ProductDetail) https://imgur.com/a/xqa6ltG

Comment: @Andrey Это у вас полные описания классов? Где поле prop int Id на продукте? Если оно есть - то вы не указали существенную часть вопроса и ведёте меня не туда, а если нету - то вы не понимаете сущность связей в навигационных полях.

Comment: Нет, не полное. Первичный ключ и т.д - есть

Comment: В бд mssql - связи работают, ибо нельзя ставить в связанный ключ - не существующий

Comment: Если id для связей таблиц есть, то просто вычеркните строку `.ThenInclude(b => b.Name)`, она вам не нужна. Вообще.

Comment: Как ни странно - вот так вот заработало
_context.ProductDetails
                .Include(b => b.Product)
                .FirstOrDefault().Product.Name; 
Спасибо)

Comment: Нет, "заработало, компилируется" и "получили то, что хотели" - разные вещи. Я вас спросил "что хотите получить", вы сказали, что ProductDetails, а запрос у вас сейчас вернёт Product. Посмотрите обновление ответа и особое внимание на строку, где я обращаюсь не к свойствам ProductDetail, но к свойствам Product.

Comment: Product и нужно было получить.
"Я хочу с таблицы ProductDetails - получить данные таблицы product"

Comment: Нет-нет, вы второй раз ведёте меня не туда. Вы сказали "я хочу ProductDetails получить". Вам не кажется, что если бы вы хотели получить данные с продукта, то можно было бы сделать  `_context.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 123456);` и у него сразу получить `.Name`? Вы же как будто летите из Питера в Москву через Владивосток: делаете лишний JOIN (а это не бесплатная операция), который избыточен и не нужен. Если вам нужна сущность продукта - то надо сразу её получать, а не брать через три сущности. Вы же не просто .Include использовали а .ThenInclude - это очень редкая операция в запросах

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо) Я Вас примерно понял. Сейчас буду все заново перечитывать. И напоследок вопрос. Указывать же [ForeignKey("")] по сути необязательно?

Comment: @Andrey В случаях, когда вы следуете конвенции -- не обязательно, EF разберётся. У вас как раз такой случай: навигационное поле Product, есть int'овое поле ProductId (т.е. Product + Id). Я первое время пока не научился видеть навигационные поля - оставлял, теперь привык и не оставляю таких костылей для лучшего понимания.

Comment: @Andrey Если у вас есть новый вопрос - задавайте его отдельно.