# Как получить связанные сущности в одной в Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

только знакомлюсь с EF Core, так что не судите строго.
Вообщем, у меня есть такая простенькая схема моего кластера.

Тут ClientId, CustomerId, ItemId просто ссылочные ключи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама сущность выглядит так:

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
    public Client Client { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ItemId")]
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

Так что по сути тут я должен (как я думаю) получать сущность Order, где все свойства инициализированы:

```
using (OrdersContext c = new OrdersContext())
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(() =>
    {
        orders = c.Orders.Find(11);
    }));
}
```

Но в итоге я получаю это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рабочий код вот, если что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот, у меня вопрос. Должен ли мне EF Core при подобном обращении к таблице-сущности (у которой есть ссылки ещё на другие сущности) возвращать инициализированные сущности в себе? Если что, в таблицах есть все записи, на которые ссылаются эти ключи в таблице Orders.

Comment: Если что, тут переменная `orders` имеет такое имя просто по ошибке. Конечно тут подразумевается что я хочу получить один `order`

Comment: Вы можете [включить LazyLoading](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/857022/213987) либо явно сделать `.Include` необходимых сущностей.

Comment: @AK Он актуален. А .Include разве не загружает в БД данные?

Comment: Он загружает *ИЗ* бд данные.

Comment: @AK Окей, спасибо)

Comment: А зачем вам такая обёртка await task factory StartNew? Используйте `return await c.Orders.FindAsync(111);`

Comment: @AK А у меня ещё логика тут будет, если я буду в объект подгружать ещё что-то.

Comment: Гм. Не сталкивался с таким, но всё равно мне кажется ваш пример можно записать более лаконично. Кроме того, именно подгрузит в объект -- это всего лишь `return await c.Orders.Include(x => x.Customer).Include(x => x.Client).FindAsync(111);`

Comment: @AK Я тоже так думаю, кстати. 
`return await c.Orders.Include(c => c.Client).ThenInclude(cust => cust.Customer).ThenInclude(item => item.Item);` 
Так?

Comment: @AK Хотя, я же не обратился к конкретному объекту. Ладно надо будет лучше разобраться в этом

Comment: Нет, ThenInclude нужен для другого сценария: вот если бы у вас у одного ордера было бы много клиентов и у каждого клиента было бы много кастомеров. См. тут например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/933396/213987

Comment: @AK Окей, Значит для одной сущности, где есть ещё свойства-сущности мне нужно использовать просто .Include(). А если я хочу вытащить ещё и в свойстве-сущности что-то, то тогда использую ThenInclude()?

Comment: @AK Просто я хотел бы получить конкретный объект Order с инициализированными свойствами, на которые он ссылается, а не целый IEnumerable<Order> с инициализированными свойствами. Нельзя ли было бы это сделать грубо говоря в одну строку, чтобы потом ещё не выбирать нужный мне объект из всех скачанных?

Comment: Ну так для того чтобы выбрать один Order, а не Enumerable вам можно использовать .Find, .First, .Single и FindOrDefault, FirstOrDefault и SingleOrDfault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете включить LazyLoading либо явно сделать `.Include()` необходимых сущностей. Поищите информацию по LazyLoading, из того, что сам отвечал нашёл такую ссылку: [Как использовать колекции в Entity Framework Core?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/857022/213987)

В целом я бы рекомендовал в вашем случае использовать Include:

```
 return await c.Orders.Include(x => x.Customer).Include(x => x.Client).FindAsync(11);
```

> А если я хочу вытащить ещё и в свойстве-сущности что-то

Не уверен, что правильно понял, но вот вам пример. Если бы у вас на диаграмме была бы у заказа к Company и у Company был бы MainPhone в отдельной сущности Phones то вы могли бы получить order с клиентами и телефонами так:

```
await c.Orders.Include(x => x.Company.MainPhone).Where(...
```

Вообще, я вам рекомендую почитать вот этот учебник по EF Core: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/ -- там много ответов на достаточно простые вопросы по азам EF. Просто прочитайте его от начала до конца, постепенно разбирая все примеры.

Comment: Насчёт того что в свойстве-сущности ещё что-то там есть, Вы меня правильно поняли. Если что, я вот так решил вопрос, немного прямолинейней чем у вас)
`orders = c.Orders
                    .Include(client => client.Client)
                    .Include(item => item.Item)
                    .Include(customer => customer.Customer).ToList();

                    foreach (var _order in orders)
                    {
                        if (_order.OrderId == 11)
                        {
                            order = _order;
                        }
                    }`

Comment: Вам достаточно вместо .ToList() использовать `.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OrderId == 11)` и цикл не понадобится. https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/5.2.php

Comment: Ну да, можно так. Надо больше в LINQ практиковаться. Спасибо за помощь)